# create dynamic form field(with validation) using nested JSON data IONIC 3(Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I want to create a questionnaire form using JSON data which will contain nested form items see below JSON data.

```
    let questions: any[] = [

  {
    linkedId: '1',
    formtype: 'dropdown',
    key: 'brave',
    label: 'Bravery Rating',
    options: [
      {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
      {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
      {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
      {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
    ],
    order: 3
  },

  {
    linkedId: '2',
    formtype: 'textbox',
    key: 'firstName',
    label: 'First name',
    value: 'Bombasto',
    required: true,
    order: 1
  },

  {
    linkedId: '3',
    formtype: 'textbox',
    key: 'emailAddress',
    label: 'Email',
    type: 'email',
    order: 2
  },

  {
    linkedId: '4',
    formtype: 'group',
    key: 'groupData',
    label: 'group Data',
    order: 4,
    items: [
      {
        linkedId: '4.1',
        formtype: 'dropdown',
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 3
      },

      {
        linkedId: '4.2',
        formtype: 'textbox',
        key: 'firstName',
        label: 'First name',
        value: 'Bombasto',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      },

      {
        linkedId: '4.3',
        formtype: 'textbox',
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and it is not only single-level nested data, it will be multi-level nested JSON data. using this JSON data need to create form fields in ionic 3 and form fields will be having validations.
please help me out here, answers will be appreciated.
can achieve in both ionic or angular.

Comment: This question is waaaay too broad as it currently sits. Have you tried anything? If so, show us that and explain the issue you are having with that code. If you haven't tried anything, then I suggest to look at: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form to get started :)

Comment: Thnaks for response, Yes i tried already the link you sent. but in that we can achieve only single level form createion.(menas in above peace of json "linkedId: 4" contaion another set of "items". i am not able to achieve it.)

Comment: Look into recursive functions in javascript :)